# web3.eth.subscribe not implemented for web3 version 1.0.0-beta.27

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum, web3js

I am on web3 version `1.0.0-beta.27` and I am running a private ethereum blockchain for testing purposes. The blockchain is mining and has two users, now I would like to `subscribe` to events in the blockchain and perform some actions. The code is below:

```
var Web3 = require("web3");     

var ether_port = 'http://localhost:8545'
var web3       = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(ether_port));

web3.eth.subscribe("pendingTransactions"
                  , function(err, result){
    if (err){ console.log(err) }
    else { console.log("result: ", result) }
});
```

I get something like:

```
Error: The current provider doesn't support subscriptions: HttpProvider
at Subscription.subscribe
```

In some sense not surprising since when I do `web3.eth.subscribe` on the `node.js` console I get:

```
{ [Function] call: undefined }
```

Even though the documentation for `web3-1.0.0` states the function can be used: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html.

1. So is this just a matter of documentation being out of sync with actual implementation? Am I using it wrong?
2. If it is not implemented, what is the best way to listen to changes in the chain? For example if I want a real time update of a user's account balance? That is aside from the naive implementation of a function that pings the chain every `n` fraction of a second.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error suggests, pub/sub is not available over HTTP. However, you can use it over WS. So, the documentation you referenced is not 100% wrong, it just omits the provider portion of the code.

Try starting your nodes using web socket connections (`geth --ws --wsport 8545 ...`, assuming you're using `geth`), and change to a `WebsocketProvider`.

```
var Web3 = require("web3");     

var ether_port = 'ws://localhost:8545'
var web3       = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(ether_port));

web3.eth.subscribe("pendingTransactions"
                  , function(err, result){
    if (err){ console.log(err) }
    else { console.log("result: ", result) }
});
```

See the 4th comment on this [discussion ticket](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/937).

Comment: Could you help me on the correct way to open a websocket in geth. When doing  `geth --identity "node" --nodiscover --maxpeers 0 --datadir /path/to/data --networkid 123 --ws --wsport 8546 console`, and then try to open a connection in node, I get `WARN [01-09|14:54:48] origin '' not allowed on WS-RPC interface`.

Comment: Try `geth --identity "node" --nodiscover --maxpeers 0 --datadir /path/to/data --networkid 123 --ws --wsport 8545 --wsaddr 0.0.0.0 --wsorigins "*" console`. Notice I used port 8545 to match the code in the answer. Obviously use whatever you want there.

Comment: Ah that worked well thank you. One last question, why is it that when I navigate to `ws://127.0.0.1:8546/` in the browser (the address I ended up using for the ws port) , I get this site can't be reached. But I can navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8546/` when I open an `http` port?

Comment: I'm not sure. I've never tried to hit it via a ws through the browser. I would suggest to use a web socket plugin to maybe get more info. Also, you can enable both JSON-RPC (HTTP) and WS connections at the same time. Just run them on separate ports. I should also mention that you should be able to do pub/sub via IPC if you need access to libs other than eth/web3/net and have security concerns with HTTP/WS.

Answer (score 0):

a better way to open it using a attached JS console

which you can attach using > geth attach 'ipc path'  (i.e. in my case it is /home/dev/.ethereum/geth.ipc)

after that you will connect to running geth node and use management API's.. now you can use

> admin.startWS("localhost", 'port number')

and when you want to close the connection then you can use below command

> admin.stopWS()

Regards
Dev